# Mock Dll in Xunit

Tags: c#, xunit

I want to mock a dll in xunit. Can anybody help me out with a solution. Below is the method where I need to mock the dll:

```
 [DllImport("arc-libs.dll", EntryPoint = "AdjustTimeZone")]
 public static extern string AdjustTimeZone(string jsonPayload);
```

Comment: You surely mean you want to mock a `static extern` method. There´s no such thing as mocking a dll. Which mocking-framework you refer to?

Comment: You can fake a static method using TypeMock Isolator or JustMock (both paid) or using MS Fakes (only available in VS Enterprise).

Answer (score 1):

I don´t know which mocking-framework you refer to, but those I know cannot mock static members, because mocking is some kind of overriding. Thus you need either an interface to mock, or at least `virtual`.

So when you have this class

```
class MyClass
{
    public virtual void DoSomething() { ... }
}
```

the mocking-framework will generate some class that derives from `MyClass`:

```
class MyMock : MyClass
{
    public override void DoSomething() { /* something different /* }
}
```

You could create a wrapper around your static method and mock that instead:

```
class MyClass
{
    [DllImport("arc-libs.dll", EntryPoint = "AdjustTimeZone")]
    public static extern string AdjustTimeZone(string jsonPayload);

    public virtual string AdjustTimeZoneWrapper(string jsonPayload) 
    => AdjustTimeZone(jsonPayload);
}
```

This however assumes clients of your class also use the wrapper-method, not the `extern` one.

Comment: but for DllImport we shld always have to use static or extern....it won't support with virtual

Comment: @shrutipatil Huum? Of course the dllimport only works for `extern`. I never said anything different. But you shouldn´t use that method in your code, only the `virtual` wrapper.